# \part and \chapter commands output both numbered and named headings

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, chapters, parts

I have the following LaTeX document being compiled in TeXstudio 2.3 on Windows 7 (mode is PdfLatex + PdfViewer):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

% Modified \part and \chapter from report.cls
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}\makeatother
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% Remove \thechapter from \thesection}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{Part One}
    \chapter[Chapter Other One]{Chapter One}
    \section{Section First}
    \subsection{Subsection X}
    Djigurda is here.
    \subsection{Castles with Penguins}
    Castles with penguins here.
\end{document}​
```

Problem is, `\chapter` command produces 2 lines in resulting PDF:

[image: Example]

So how do I turn off numbered headings? I want only `Chapter One` to appear.

Comment: What about `Chapter One`'s `Chapter 1`? Also, do you want `\part` to show up in the ToC?

Comment: @Werner same for chapters — named only. And I want them both in ToC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a set of redefinitions of sectional units in [`report.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls). It removes the number of `\part` and `\chapter` to be printed in the ToC, as well as the main report body. However, the counters are still incremented in order to reset other slave counters, as is necessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
%\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
%\usepackage[english]{babel}% http://ctan.org/pkg/babel

% Modified \part and \chapter from report.cls
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {#1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}% Remove \thechapter from \thesection}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \part{Part One}
    \chapter[Chapter Other One]{Chapter One}
    \section{Section First}
    \subsection{Subsection X}
    Djigurda is here.
    \subsection{Castles with Penguins}
    Castles with penguins here.
\end{document}​
```

The affected macros are

- `\@part` (removed printing `Part \thepart` and including `\thepart` in the ToC);
- `\@chapter` (removed printing `\thechapter` in the ToC);
- `\@makechapterhead` (removed printing `Chapter \thechapter` in the chapter heading); and
- `\thesection` (removed printing `\thechapter` as part of the counter).

Comment: Thank you!

Somehow it made to work only `\part` (`\chapter` still gives both numbered and named headings)

Comment: @Constantius: And you included (copy-and-paste) the redefinition of both `\@chapter` and `\@makechapterhead`? If this is the case, what other packages do you include that could affect the sectioning commands? [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) or perhaps [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty)?

Comment: in fact, I tried bare example you provided — works for `\part`, but not for `\chapter` (there is no packages included at all)

Comment: @Constantius: ToC entries are accumulated over at least two compile runs. If you did that and *still* get numbered chapters in the ToC with my MWE, then I don't know what to say... Perhaps include the *exact* code and *exact* output as part of your original question (via an [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/70621/edit)).

Comment: ToC is okay, problem is in document itself. Will edit the question now

Comment: finished edits now

Comment: @Constantius: I've updated my answer. There was an unwanted `\makeatother` at the end of `\@chapter` that didn't allow the redefinition of `\@makechapterhead`, leading to the original construction being still used.

Comment: @Werner Do you know how you could make your solution "work" inside an article environment? (for the Parts, of course). I've tried your code but I get a ! Undefined control sequence. I said "work" because it seems to be doing what I want, despite the error. I'll post a question if you can't reproduce.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: So you switched from `report` to `article`. Do you want the **chapters** to now be **sections** (**bold** font), and everything else similar?

Comment: In fact, I use the exam class, which uses the same sectioning as article IIRC. I only want the \part header to be removed so \part{mypart} would print mypart rather than Part 1  mypart

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien: With a specialized class, I think it's best to ask a [follow-up question](http://goo.gl/vWjuk).

Comment: Yup figured much, I'll ping when it's done. Thanks

Comment: The new question is http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183415/making-the-part-1-disappear-in-part-format