# Making the "Part 1" disappear in \part format

Tags: sectioning, numbering, parts

I am making a bank of exercises for a course. To do this, I use the exam class, which uses the same sectioning as the article class.

To do this, I have a separate .tex files with the questions, inside sections, subsections that uses the exam class format.

The main .tex file consists only of a \Part{Questions} \input{questions.tex} and a \Part{Answers} \input{questions.tex}.  When the \part is printed, it gives the following:

**Part I**

**Questions**

I would like to remove the Part 1 header.

@Werner has a solution in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70621/part-and-chapter-commands-output-both-numbered-and-named-headings/70624?noredirect=1#comment422667_70624), where the report class had been used. Using is solution seems to work, but LaTeX gives me a undefined control sequence for each \part I have.

Here is a MWE without Werner's solution

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}                             
\firstpagefooter{}{}{\thepage}
\firstpagefootrule
\runningheadrule
\runningheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}  
\runningfooter{Nom du professeur}{}{\thepage}
\runningfootrule
\title{Banque d'exercices pour MAT-1720}
\author{Nom du professeur - Institut}
\date{Automne 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part{Questions}
\noprintanswers
\begin{questions}
\newcounter{NombredeQ}
\setcounter{NombredeQ}{1}
\newcounter{NombredeR}
\setcounter{NombredeR}{1}
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\newpage
\part{Solutions}
\qformat{\shadowbox{\textbf{Solution à l'exercice} \theNombredeQ}  \hfill}
\printanswers
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

And now the same code with Werner's code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
    {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries  #2\par}%
    \@endpart}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}                             
\firstpagefooter{}{}{\thepage}
\firstpagefootrule
\runningheadrule
\runningheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}  
\runningfooter{Nom du professeur}{}{\thepage}
\runningfootrule
\title{Banque d'exercices pour MAT-1720}
\author{Nom du professeur - Institut}
\date{Automne 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part{Questions}
\noprintanswers
\begin{questions}
\newcounter{NombredeQ}
\setcounter{NombredeQ}{1}
\newcounter{NombredeR}
\setcounter{NombredeR}{1}
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\newpage
\part{Solutions}
\printanswers
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

It gives the intended results, but leaves an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a major difference in how `\part`s are set in the [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) (used by [`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam)) and [`report`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/report.cls) classes. Most notably is the that the latter sets an entire page for the part.

From your example code, the only unknown causing the error is `\@endpart`, which only exists in the `report` class. Instead, `article` ends a `\part` using `\@afterheading`. So you could add

```
\makeatletter
\let\@endpart\@afterheading
\makeatother
```

to your preamble to remove the error, if you're also okay with the eventual typeset result.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\uplevel` macro provided by `exam` class.

```
\uplevel{\centering\Huge\bfseries Questions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Questions}
```

If you wish, you can turn this in to a macro:

```
\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
\phantomsection   %% to make links work
\uplevel{\centering\Huge\bfseries #1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}
}
```

and use it like

```
\mypart{Questions}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{\thepage}
\firstpagefootrule
\runningheadrule
\runningheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}
\runningfooter{Nom du professeur}{}{\thepage}
\runningfootrule
\title{Banque d'exercices pour MAT-1720}
\author{Nom du professeur - Institut}
\date{Automne 2014}

\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
\phantomsection
\uplevel{\centering\Huge\bfseries #1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\mypart{Questions}
\noprintanswers
\begin{questions}
\newcounter{NombredeQ}
\setcounter{NombredeQ}{1}
\newcounter{NombredeR}
\setcounter{NombredeR}{1}
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM?
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM?
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\newpage
\mypart{Solutions}
\printanswers
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM?
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM?
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to refer to these parts, You can use a newcounter:

```
\newcounter{mypart}
\setcounter{mypart}{0}
\newcommand{\mypart}[1]{%
\phantomsection
\refstepcounter{mypart}
\label{mypart:#1}
\uplevel{\centering\Huge\bfseries #1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}
}
```

so that labels are automatically created with (say) `{mypart:Questions}` when you use `\mypart{Questions}` and you can use them like

```
refer~\ref{mypart:Questions} here
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the use of the exam class command. It would seems that the reference pointed by the TOC aren't working properly though.

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien Add a `\phantomsection`. Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

You have to patch the `\@part` command as defined in the `article` class; it's different than in `report`.

The simplest way is to use `\patchcmd`, but this must be done before loading `hyperref`, which changes the definition of `\@part` based on what there was before.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,fancybox} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@part}{\phantomsection}{}{} % for links (requires hyperref)
\patchcmd{\@part}{\m@ne}{\maxdimen}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@part}{\m@ne}{\maxdimen}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\firstpageheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}                             
\firstpagefooter{}{}{\thepage}
\firstpagefootrule
\runningheadrule
\runningheader{Probabilités}{}{MAT-1720}  
\runningfooter{Nom du professeur}{}{\thepage}
\runningfootrule
\title{Banque d'exercices pour MAT-1720}
\author{Nom du professeur - Institut}
\date{Automne 2014}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{headandfoot}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\part{Questions}
\noprintanswers
\begin{questions}
\newcounter{NombredeQ}
\setcounter{NombredeQ}{1}
\newcounter{NombredeR}
\setcounter{NombredeR}{1}
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\newpage
\part{Solutions}
\qformat{\shadowbox{\textbf{Solution à l'exercice} \theNombredeQ}  \hfill}
\printanswers
\section{ Dénombrement  }
\subsection{Principes de dénombrement}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}  Ceci est une question test. Quel est le sigle du cours probabilités à l'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question.  }}
\begin{solution}
Le sigle est MAT-1720.
\end{solution}
\subsection{Permutations et Combinaisons}
\question \ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\label{R:\theNombredeR}}{\label{Q:\thequestion}}
 Ceci est une autre question test. Quel est le nom du cours qui a pour sigle MAT-1720 à L'UdeM? 
\\\ifthenelse{\boolean{printanswers}}{\textbf{Retour à la question \ref{Q:\theNombredeQ}.}\stepcounter{NombredeQ} \stepcounter{NombredeR}}{\textbf{Voir la \hyperref[R:\thequestion]{solution} à la question. }}
\begin{solution}
Le cours est probabilité.
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to change the two conditionals `\ifnum\c@secnumdepth>\m@ne` into `\ifnum\c@secnumdepth}>\maxdimen`; `\m@ne` stands for –1, while `\maxdimen` is the largest expressible number.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. TOC links aren't working though

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien As usual in these cases `\phantomsection` helps. Fixed.